# Does 一屁股坐下来 just mean 'sit down' or is there some other meaning in there?

Tags: meaning

一屁股坐下来 seems a bit of a strange thing to say. Does it just mean 'sit down'?

Can I say to you '一屁股坐下来' to you to invite you to sit?

In English, as a command, I might say 'sit your arse down!' (stay there, don't move)

Comment: This is not a command. It is a figurative way to describe somebody "sat down quickly". (I cannot find a proper English word here, so I am waiting others to answer)

Comment: It has the same effect as  一大口吞進去 (swallowed something in one large gulp like drinking soup or water, almost like they’re going to choke), if that makes any sense

Comment: cf。bkrs:一12) (Ru) abruptly, suddenly,at once, (abrupt transition to new state or action, expressed by following verb) 
天气一凉   (it suddenly turned chilly)
他累得蒙头一睡  
他都不管甩手一走

Comment: 某用户的粗俗很可能把大多数的用户都驱使出了

Answer (score 7):

The literal meaning of 一屁股坐下来 is "sit down with one move of one's butt". It is a description of a manner which implies "abruptly with no hesitation"

There are similar adverbial phrases:

一手 (with one move of one's hand)

一手搶過我手中的香煙 (with one move of his hand, he grabs the cigarette off my hand = he takes the cigarette off my hand with one move of his hand)

一腳 (with one move of one's foot)

一腳把球射入龍門 (with one strike of his foot, he kicked the ball into the goal = he kicks the ball into the goal with a single strike)

"**一屁股坐下来**" would mean "he sits down with one move of his butt ", therefore it can be described simply as "**sit down abruptly** (with no hesitation)"

*"One move" implies "one(quick/sudden)move"*

Answer (score 0):

'一屁股坐下来' isn't used as a command. It's not the same as the sentence you quoted "take your arse down". Take your arse down would be like saying "给我坐下！" or "你给我她妈坐下！".

'一屁股坐下来', however, is used to describe someone is impolite or rude. They just sit directly without being invited by the host. For example, 你这个人真没有礼貌，到别人家里不管不顾，一屁股就坐下来了！

It can also be used to describe someone sits abruptly without paying attention to something on the chair, which could be crushed by his sitting. For example, 你这一屁股坐下来，把我的手机都坐坏了！

Basically, it's used to describe one's sitting in a way of either being rude or careless.

Comment: sit down abruptly can be considered impolite or rude in some circumstances, but not always. For example,  if you  just get home from work and 一屁股坐在沙发上, it  just mean you switch to relax mode abruptly

Comment: @TangHo you are right, but that can be a careless sitting.

Answer (score -1):

哈哈，作为中国人，我给你解答一下，“一屁股坐下来”就是“坐下来的速度很快（原因：受到惊吓，或者震惊产生的反应）” someone sits down faster cause he is scary or shocked.

Comment: Can you add an English translation of your answer?