# What does the first part of 它一把拉着我跳回了家，我成了兔子，而它成了我的模样 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I've taken to reading short essays written by grade-five children (五年纪作文).  In [沙发上的兔子](http://www.ruiwen.com/zuowen/wunianjizuowen/1927149.html) (Rabbit on the Sofa), there's an image of a rabbit on the sofa, and when the child falls asleep, the child turns into a rabbit, and the rabbit becomes the child.

However, I don't understand the first part of this sentence:

> 它一把拉着我跳回了家，我成了兔子，而它成了我的模样

**Question**: What does 它一把拉着我跳回了家 mean?

I'd guess something in the ballpark of "it pulled me back home", but don't really know what this means.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%AE%83%E4%B8%80%E6%8A%8A%E6%8B%89%E7%9D%80%E6%88%91%E8%B7%B3%E5%9B%9E%E4%BA%86%E5%AE%B6%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E6%88%90%E4%BA%86%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%EF%BC%8C%E8%80%8C%E5%AE%83%E6%88%90%E4%BA%86%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%A1%E6%A0%B7) and [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%AE%83%E4%B8%80%E6%8A%8A%E6%8B%89%E7%9D%80%E6%88%91%E8%B7%B3%E5%9B%9E%E4%BA%86%E5%AE%B6%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E6%88%90%E4%BA%86%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%EF%BC%8C%E8%80%8C%E5%AE%83%E6%88%90%E4%BA%86%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%A1%E6%A0%B7) respectively give:

> It pulled me back home, I became a rabbit, and it became my appearance.
>
> He grabbed me and jumped back home. I became a rabbit, and he became me.

There's some kind of magic going on here, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the story, "它" in "它一把拉着我跳回了家" is referring to the rabbit. --> "It (the rabbit) pulling me along and hopped back home"

As for the function of "一把", you can reference my answer to this [question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30190/does-%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%81%E8%82%A1%E5%9D%90%E4%B8%8B%E6%9D%A5-just-mean-sit-down-or-is-there-some-other-meaning-in-there):

> *It is a description of a manner which implies "abruptly with no hesitation"
>   There are similar adverbial phrases:*
>
> *一手 (with one move of one's hand)*
>
> *一手搶過我手中的香煙 (with one move of his hand, he grabs the cigarette off my hand = he takes the cigarette off my hand with one move of his hand)*

- 它拉着我跳回了家 = he pulling me hopped back home
- 它(一把)拉着我跳回了家 = he (with one swift grab) pulling me hopped back home

> 我成了兔子，而它成了我的模样
>
> I turned into a rabbit, and it (the rabbit) turned into my appearance.
>
> *Notice the phrase "it hopped home", which mean before they got home, the rabbit was still a rabbit.  Once arrived home, the rabbit turned into the child; and the child turned into a rabbit (obviously a dream)*

Answer (score 1):

They switched places.

The "我" became the rabbit, (when the rabbit pulled the "我" home, presumably to the rabbit's house), and they miraculously switched places; the "我" becoming the rabbit, and the rabbit took on the "我's" appearance, (它成了我的模样)

Why do I assume it was the rabbit who pulled the "我" home? Because the sentence started with “它”, ("it") which is used when referring to animals. So it was an animal, (a rabbit), who pulled the "我" home. This would make sense when they eventually switched places / appearances.

Answer (score 1):

"He grabbed me and jumped back home." is its literal translation.

According to the context, it's all in his dream. As we all know, dreams usually go like movies. It's a way to describe the scene has been switched suddenly(like a movie) - picturing "**jumping back home, he and the rabbit**". After jumping into his home, their roles switched.

Answer (score 1):

它一把拉着我跳回了家，
Here “一把” is a key word that hinders your understanding however it makes the sentence more vivid. 
Let me see the "Modern Chinese Dictionary":
“一” 数词.表示动作是短暂的。Numeral.Refer to an action of transitory or short time.
“把” 量词.用于手的动作。 Measure word.An action use of the hand.
“他拉着我跳回了家”is same meaning， but to add “一把” Make the sentence come to more vivid。 
另：“五年纪作文”应该是“五年级”

Answer (score 1):

它一把拉着我跳回了家 means it pulled me back to home by jumping back to home.

In this example, 它 is pronoun means 兔子.

In this example, 一把拉着 show a action that pull something(我).

In this example, 我 means me.

In this example, 跳 means jump.

In this example, 回了家 means back to home.

Comment: "它一把拉着我跳回了家 means it pull me when it jumped back to home." This interpretation is incorrect. It should be *it pulled me back home.* Your interpretation sounds like *it tried to block my jumping back home*.

Comment: Fixed, I use "it pulled me back to home by jumping back to home."